I have two GFCI outlets Daisy chained,would like to replace one with a standard outlet how do I wire when connecting the standard outlet
Original GFCI keeps tripping so I'm replacing both GFCIs but found that two GFCIs in series is not necessary in residential, so I'd like to replace one of them with a standard outlet but don't know how to deal with the four wires.
I have two black wires, two white wires and a brass ground. One black wire and one white wire comes from each Romex coming into the box. Two from upstream and two from downstream.

Please post pictures showing how the existing outlets are wired at both boxes.  Turn off the circuit breaker (don't forget to test by plugging a known working device into each outlet), remove the face plates and pull out the outlets so that the wires and any wire nuts are clearly visible.  Take pictures and add to your post (sun and mountains icon, or post a link to an image service where you uploaded the pictures).  Pictures of the two new outlets would help as well.

Before turning the power off, run a quick test to find out which one is first in the circuit.  Plug a small lamp into outlet A, and push the test button on outlet B.  If the lamp loses power you'll know that B is the downstream outlet which is the one you want to replace with a standard outlet.  If not, reset the GFCI on A,  plug the lamp into A, and press the test button on B.  Now the lamp should go off, and you know that you need to replace outlet A.

Do you know which GFCI is the line and which is the load?


Original GFCI keeps tripping

So frustrating - I've had to replace the radon detector in my basement 5 times, they keep going off!   /s
Laugh, but people really think like that when GFCIs trip. "I don't know how to see a ground fault, therefore it's fake news and the detector is faulty".
So yeah, I wouldn't get my hopes up. Your new one is as likely to trip and you'll still have to chase the ground fault, just with $20 less in your pocket.
Since you want to replace the GFCI anyway, why not just move GFCI #2 to GFCI #1 position?
Once GFCI #1 is exonerated, you now have a spare.

I'd like to replace one of them with a standard outlet but don't know how to deal with the four wires.

You're saying that the first GFCI tripping also takes out the second GFCI.  That wiring is already correct for what you're trying to do.  Simply pay attention to LINE and LOAD, brass and silver, and move the wires to same terminals on the new GFCI.
Remember to use a torque screwdriver if torques are indicated, this is a new rule at 110.14(D) in response to recent science showing it matters to avoid terminal burn-ups and fire.
The second GFCI, just replace it with a plain receptacle and apply any labeling in any non-handwritten style that say "GFCI Protected", and if applicable "No Equipment Ground".  Bonus points if it also says where to find the reset.
